# How to find a cheap tour to Wieliczka salt mines from Krakow?

Tags: tours, poland, krakow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to visit Wieliczka salt mines and the Auschwitz KZ from Krakow?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5372/how-to-visit-wieliczka-salt-mines-and-the-auschwitz-kz-from-krakow)

Just this. If I'm at Krakow, which are the cheapest tour that goes to the salt mines?

Comment: I don't start a discussion about this, but the difference between "how to go by my own" and "cheap tour" is big.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are really dozens of tour operators that offers tours to the Salt Mines. I would recommend to use collect some flyers and compare the conditions. I personally can recommend the tour that is provided by the [Mosquito Hostel in Krakow](http://www.mosquitohostel.com/). They have an agreement with a tour operator that picks you up directly in front of the hostel and then drives you there in a comfortable minibus. After the tour you're picked up at the mines and you can again leave the minibus directly in front of the hostel or in the old town center.

The price was 10 Euro per person including everything, which I personally think is very reasonable. But we got a student discount of 50%, so the normal price is a little bit higher.

I assume that other tour operators have more or less the same offers.

Comment: The "problem" is we have a book in another hostel, is mandatory to stay at this hostel to make this tour?

Comment: I don't think so, and I think a lot of hostels offer similar tours.